# TensorFlow fails for DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA

Tags: python, tensorflow, video, nvidia

I get the following error:

```
Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
Fille "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\DeepFaceLab\core\joblib\SubprocessorBase.py", line 62, in _subprocess_run
self.on_initialize(client_dict)
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\DeepFaceLab\mainscripts\Extractor.py", line 66, in on_initialize
nn.initialize (device_config)
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\DeepFaceLab\core\leras\nn.py", line 80, in initialize
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\fredd\Desktop\DeepFaceLab_NVIDIA\_internal\python-3.6.8\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "imp.py", line 243, in load_module
File "imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I already tried to downgrade tensorflow, different Python-versions,

Here the code: [enter link description here](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab)

I appreciate your help!!!

[image]

Comment: Same error here.